# Hibernate one to many relation defined in xml is not working

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, maven

post is long but it is because I wanted to explain everything good enough to let you help me. I have created two tables and i would like to create one to many relation using hibernate (each customer can have many orders). the way I created this tables is shown there:

```
create table if not exists customer(
    customer_id int not null auto_increment,
    first_name varchar(50),
    last_name varchar(50),
    primary key (customer_id)
);

create table if not exists orders(
    order_id int not null auto_increment,
    order_date timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
    adress varchar(50),
    customer int not null,
    primary key (order_id),
    foreign key (customer) references customer(customer_id)
);
```

Now I would like to create java project and connect this project with my database using hibernate.

Dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.15</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <mapping resource="application.hbm.xml" />
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

application.hbm.xml in which i create connection between entities and database columns:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entity.Customer" table="customer">
        <id name="idCustomer" column="customer_id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" column="first_name" />
        <property name="lastName" column="last_name" />
        <set name="orders" inverse="true" cascade="persist" >
            <key column="order_id" />
            <one-to-many class="entity.Order" />
        </set>
    </class>

    <class name="entity.Order" table="orders">
        <id name="idOrder" column="order_id">
            <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="orderDate" column="order_date"></property>
        <property name="adress" column="adress"></property>
        <many-to-one name="customer" column="customer" not-null="true" />
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Customer entity:

```
package entity;

import java.util.Set;

public class Customer {

    private long idCustomer;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Set<Order> orders;
    public long getIdCustomer() {
        return idCustomer;
    }
    public void setIdCustomer(long idCustomer) {
        this.idCustomer = idCustomer;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public Set<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }
    public void setOrders(Set<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String returnString =  "Customer [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
        returnString += "\nOrders: ";
        for(Order order : orders) {
            returnString = returnString +"\n" +  order;
        }

        return returnString;
    }
}
```

Order entity:

```
package entity;

import java.util.Date;

public class Order {
    private int idOrder;
    private Date orderDate;
    private String adress;
    private Customer customer;

    public int getIdOrder() {
        return idOrder;
    }

    public void setIdOrder(int idOrder) {
        this.idOrder = idOrder;
    }

    public Date getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }

    public void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order [idOrder=" + idOrder + ", orderDate=" + orderDate + ", adress=" + adress + "]";
    }
}
```

until this moment, everything works, when i am running in a main method a code like this:

```
        Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory factory = conf.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        Customer customer = (Customer) session.get(Customer.class, 1l);


        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setAdress("plac strzelecki 212");
        order.setOrderDate(new Date());
        order.setCustomer(customer);

        customer.getOrders().add(order);
        session.save(customer);
        transaction.commit();

        session.close();
```

the order is saved in database. But after trying to load this customer and show its orders, the code shows that customer has no orders...eg when i do something like this:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory factory = conf.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    Customer customer = (Customer) session.get(Customer.class, 1l);


    System.out.println(customer.getOrders().size());

    session.close();
```

The output is 0...what am I doing wrong? Or what am i not understanding properly?

Comment: Can you show the code that you used to add orders to the database? Also, is there a particular reason you're using XML configuration and not annotations?

Comment: the code I used to add order ( I added only one order) Is shown up there. Its the second one from the bottom. I am using xml configuration instead of annotations because I found good tutorial, if you have any good tutorial that clarifies everything very good then I would be very thankful if you could post it there.

Comment: It's really hard to say just looking at the code. Here are a few things you can try: Check the database after the insert to ensure that the orders are actually being saved. Set logging to "debug" to see more of what hibernate is doing. You don't need to specify every column in your mapping file, all you need is the `class` line and `id`. Sdd the property `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>` to your XML and Hibernate will delete the table and start anew each time.
https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-log4j-in-hibernate-project/